# Excel 64 bit and SQL Server CE 4 Private Deployment with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, excel, sql-server-ce, vsto

I am deploying a SQL Server CE 4.0 database which uses Entity Framework 6 with my VSTO Excel Add-In.

On development machine communication with database is working fine however on testing PC with Excel 64bit, I get an exception:

> The ADO.NET provide with invariant name 'System.Data.SQlServerCe.40' is either not registered in the machine or application config file

Same configuration but with Excel 32bit the communication with db is established without any problem. The OS on both testing PCs are Win7 - 64bit

I've checked that in deployed folder all libraries (x86 and amd64) are present.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm using SQLCE for a VSTO (and I recently switched to plain COM) plugin for Word, and the private install of SqlCE doesn't work (same error that you are seeing). I have to install it publicly for it to work, which is NOT what I want.

Comment: I dumped the idea of private deployment SQLCE, hence did an installer with installation of SQLCE on user pc, which solves all problems.